# What verb represents acting with optimism, enthusiasm and vitality?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What verb represents acting with optimism, enthusiasm and vitality?
As in an admonition, "Go forth and ______."  "A leader must be seen to _______." Perhaps it is a word similar to *vivify, vitalize, strive, thrive, prosper* or *inspire.*

Comment: Invigorate?....

Comment: Just type i.e. `define enthusiasm` in Google (set it to English) and see the list in the very first result.

Comment: It ***is*** *prosper* and *inspire*:  "Go forth and *prosper*" (Or perhaps 'Live long ...') and "A leader must be seen to *inspire*"

Comment: More philosophically, is there a word that might come closer to this?   Wordsworth - The Happy Warrior --  Whom neither shape of danger can dismay,
Nor thought of tender happiness betray;
Who, not content that former worth stand fast,
Looks forward, persevering to the last,
From well to better, daily self-surpast:

Comment: Marw - "enthuse" leads to "inspirit," which unfortunately is archiac and apparently transitive.  Getting closer.  If charisma had a verb counterpart, what would it be?

Answer (score 3):

Try **rally**. The full text at the last link captures more of the *optimism, enthusiasm and vitality* you mention in your question.

> 2a :  to arouse for action [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rally)
>
> 1 (Of troops) come together again in order to continue fighting after a defeat or dispersion: *'De Montfort’s troops rallied and drove back the king’s infantry'* [- oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rally)
>
> When you hit that last mile in the race and are so tired you want to quit, that's when you rally, finding the strength to pick up the pace. [- vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rally)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **positivize**

> Definition: to actively search for the positive; to reinforce a positive aspect or change a negative one.
>
> Example: *She engages each individual's own healing power to change behavior, positivize thinking patterns, and reveal specific guidance*.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat difficult to find a good antonym verb for *procrastinate*.  Go forth and procrastinate!

First thing that came to mind is the traditional idiom *carpe diem* or *seize the day*.  "Seize" is at least a verb and can be imperative.

A good adjective is *proactive*.

But for verbs, I first thought ***execute*** as fitting as long as it's clear by context which meaning you are using.   Since both your examples are intransitive, perhaps it is clear:

> [***execute***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/execute) -  intransitive verb:
>
> *to perform properly or skillfully* the fundamentals of a sport ...
>
> [***execute***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/execute) -
>
> To execute means to carry out in full or perform. If you execute all the difficult steps of the dance perfectly, you will make your instructor proud.

*Accomplish* is also a close synonym, though I see it as less imperative than *execute.*

Answer (score 0):

Go forth and conquer.

A leader must be seen to conquer adversity.

Though there are moral implications to conquest, one has to be optimistic, enthusiastic and energetic to be a conqueror.  I would expect the surrounding text to provide context as to whether the negative moral implications of conquest apply to this person, or whether inspirational leadership in overcoming all obstacles is intended.